# I am currently using Azure AD v1 (ADAL) to authenticate. How can I add support for Outlook.com accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, onedrive, adal, azure-ad-msal

I need to use the advanced authentication scenarios available in ADAL that aren't available in MSAL.

In addition, I want an outlook.com user (live.com / personal account) to be able to sign in.

The [Live SDK isn't available,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn631819.aspx) yet I am able to create new app identifiers [within the portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList).

**Question**

- If my goal is to support ADALv1, and also to support LiveID accounts, which route should I go?

I'm considering having a two page authentication screen, similar to what Azure and Office already do, and query the email address as shown below.

```
http://odc.officeapps.live.com/odc/emailhrd/getidp?hm=0&emailAddress=email@domain.com

https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealmExtended.srf?login=EMAIL@COMPANY.com
```

If there is only a user account in AD, then I'll transparently redirect to AzureAD.

If there is only an account in Outlook.com/live.com then I'll redirect there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the limitation you were handling. However, the portal you mentioned is register the app for the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

Is it helpful to provider a separate button to login in for Azure AD account in your scenario? If yes you can refer the code below:

Provider two buttons to choose which account to sign-in:

```
<input type="button" value="AzureAD" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account",new { provider="aad"} )'" />
<input type="button" value="Microsoft" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account",new { provider="microsoft"} )'" />
```

Account Controller:

```
public void SignIn(string provider,string ReturnUrl = "/")
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if ("aad" == provider)
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = ReturnUrl }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        else
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = ReturnUrl }, "Microsoft");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        clientId: "",
        clientSecret: "");

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "",
        Authority = "",
    });
```